# How can I isolate nested form?

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm very new to AngularJS, and new to client side programming.

**Context:**

I'm implementing a contact form with support for multiple phone numbers and addresses.

It look like  this:

```
<form name="contactInsertForm" ng-controller="contactInsertController as contactCtrlr" ng-submit="contactInsertForm.$valid && contactCtrlr.save()">
    <input type="text" name="name" />
    <phones-editor></phones-editor>
    <addresses-editor></addresses-editor>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

`phonesEditor` and `addressesEditor` are custom Angular directives which implement support for adding, removing and editing phones and addresses. The controllers and modules look like this:

**Addresses:**

```
(function () {
    var app = angular.module("AddressesEditorModule", []);
    app.directive("addressesEditor", function () {
        return {
            restrict: "E",
            templateUrl: "/addressesEditorTemplate.html",
            controller: function ($scope) {
                this.addresses = [
                    // this will hold addresses.
                ];

                // ...
            }
        }
})();
```

**Phones:**

```
(function () {
    var app = angular.module("PhonesEditorModule", []);
    app.directive("phonesEditor", function () {
        return {
            restrict: "E",
            templateUrl: "/phonesEditorTemplate.html",
            controller: function ($scope) {
                this.phones = [
                    // this will hold phones.
                ];

                // ...
            }
        }
})();
```

And the templates:

**Addresses:**

```
<!-- list already added addresses -->
<div ng-repeat="address in addressesEditorCtrlr.addresses">
    <p>{{address.address}}</p>
    <p>{{address.city}}</p>
</div>
<form name="addressInsertForm" ng-submit="addressInsertForm.$valid && addressesEditorCtrlr.add()">
    <!-- inputs for each of the address fields -->
    <input type="submit" value="Add" />
</form>
```

**Phones:**

```
<!-- list already added phones -->
<div ng-repeat="phone in phonesEditorCtrlr.addresses">
    <p>{{phone.number}}</p>
    <p>{{phone.areaCode}}</p>
</div>
<form name="phoneInsertForm" ng-submit="phoneInsertForm.$valid && phonesEditorCtrlr.add()">
    <!-- inputs for each of the phone fields -->
    <input type="submit" value="Add" />
</form>
```

As you may have noticed, the generated at the browser HTML looks like this:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="name" />
    <phones-editor>
        <!-- list already added phones -->
        <div ng-repeat="phone in phonesEditorCtrlr.addresses">
            <p>{{phone.number}}</p>
            <p>{{phone.areaCode}}</p>
        </div>
        <form name="phoneInsertForm" ng-submit="phoneInsertForm.$valid && phonesEditorCtrlr.add()">
            <!-- inputs for each of the phone fields -->
            <input type="submit" value="Add" />
        </form>
    </phones-editor>
    <addresses-editor>
        <!-- list already added addresses -->
        <div ng-repeat="address in addressesEditorCtrlr.addresses">
            <p>{{address.address}}</p>
            <p>{{address.city}}</p>
        </div>
        <form name="addressInsertForm" ng-submit="addressInsertForm.$valid && addressesEditorCtrlr.add()">
            <!-- inputs for each of the address fields -->
            <input type="submit" value="Add" />
        </form>
    </addresses-editor>
</form>
```

**The problem:**

I have two `form`'s inside a `form`. The nested forms work correctly, adding and validating values it should be doing, and refusing to add invalid phones/addresses.

But when I click the `submit` button at the outer form, it will interpret the inner forms input fields and will raise errors if these fields have invalid values.

How can I use AngularJS form handling and avoid this situation? Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 2):

you would need a directive if you want child form as isolate form. Have a look at answers from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19333544/skip-nested-forms-validation-with-angularjs). please have a look at fiddle attached in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24936234/1139099). I am putting the fiddle link here for you to [js-fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gikoo/qNrFX/) to see it in action.

putting below code just because SO doesnt accept only fiddle links...

```
<form name="parent">
    <input type="text" ng-model="outside"/>
    <ng-form name="subform" isolate-form>
        <input type="text" ng-model="inside"/>
    </ng-form>
</form>
```

Comment: This seems to be what I want, but my inner submit button do not work anymore. None of the examples had a submit button at the inner form.

Comment: When I click at the inner submit, it does nothing, not even an error at the console.

Comment: Yes, I'll update my question as soon as I finish it.

Comment: [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/qS0AYbiELRNeSswzn4v0?p=preview) outer form is valid and inner is invalid

Comment: Still, when you click the `Inner Submit` button, the outer form is submitted, not the inner as expected. The validation though works correctly.

Comment: unfortunately there is no way to fix that... [read here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15937294/angularjs-how-to-trigger-submit-in-a-nested-form)

Comment: oh =/ thank you anyway... at last I have a better understanding of `ngForm`!

Comment: please consider accepting the answers which takes question to logical conclusion...

Comment: I'd probably just use a regular button and then post whatever data I'm interested in through AngularJS via ng-click. It's more work, but you'll be able to send only the data you want that button to send. In my case, my buttons all end up calling various API methods via factories to send data to and from the server.

Answer (score 2):

Working on Angular 1.6

```
const isolatedFormDirective = () => {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: '?form',
        link: ($scope, $element, $attrs, ctrl) => {
            ctrl && ctrl.$$parentForm && ctrl.$$parentForm.$removeControl(ctrl);
        }
    }
}

app.directive('isolatedForm', isolatedFormDirective);
```

Answer (score 1):

This **[article](http://www.benlesh.com/2013/03/angular-js-validating-form-elements-in.html)** has exactly what you are looking for.

The basic gist is that you want to use the **[ngForm](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngForm)** directive inside your form tag.

```
<div ng-form="outerForm">
  <input type="text" ng-model="main.outerFormText"/>
  <div ng-form="innerForm">
    <input type="text" ng-model="main.innerFormText" required/>
    <button type="button" ng-click="main.submit('innerForm')"
      ng-disabled="innerForm.$invalid">Inner Submit</button>
  </div>
  <button type="button" ng-click="main.submit('outerForm')"
    ng-disabled="outerForm.$invalid">Outer Submit</button>
</div>
```

[Example plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/7OGC75bngWGciwdYDjmM?p=preview)

Comment: If I understood correctly, `ngForm` will cause my outer form to check the validity of the inner form. What I want is it to completely ignore my inner form.

Comment: If I remove the ng-disabled attributes, I'm still able to submit at the inner form, despite the required attribute being present.